# After implementing In app messaging I am getting duplicate class dagger

Tags: dagger, firebase-in-app-messaging

Here is my Dependencies file

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'

implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
implementation group: 'androidx.viewpager', name: 'viewpager', version: '1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging:19.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is what duplicate class error i'm getting

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class dagger.Binds found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.BindsOptionalOf found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.Component found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.Component$Builder found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.Lazy found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.MapKey found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.MembersInjector found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.Module found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.Provides found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.Reusable found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.Subcomponent found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.Subcomponent$Builder found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.Beta found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.DaggerCollections found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.DelegateFactory found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.DoubleCheck found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.Factory found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.GwtIncompatible found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.InstanceFactory found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.MapFactory found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.MapProviderFactory found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.MapProviderFactory$1 found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.MapProviderFactory$Builder found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.MembersInjectors found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.MembersInjectors$NoOpMembersInjector found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.Preconditions found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.ProviderOfLazy found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.SetFactory found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.SetFactory$1 found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.SetFactory$Builder found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.internal.SingleCheck found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.multibindings.ClassKey found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.multibindings.ElementsIntoSet found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.multibindings.IntKey found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.multibindings.IntoMap found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.multibindings.IntoSet found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.multibindings.LongKey found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.multibindings.Multibinds found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class dagger.multibindings.StringKey found in modules dagger-2.24.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24) and dagger-2.7.jar (dagger-2.7.jar)
  Duplicate class javax.inject.Inject found in modules javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject-1.jar) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
  Duplicate class javax.inject.Named found in modules javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject-1.jar) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
  Duplicate class javax.inject.Provider found in modules javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject-1.jar) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
  Duplicate class javax.inject.Qualifier found in modules javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject-1.jar) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
  Duplicate class javax.inject.Scope found in modules javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject-1.jar) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
  Duplicate class javax.inject.Singleton found in modules javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject-1.jar) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:151)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.StartSnapshotTaskInputsBuildOperationTaskExecuter.execute(StartSnapshotTaskInputsBuildOperationTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor.process(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.executeWithServices(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:178)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:154)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:24)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:383)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:247)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:159)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
............................................
```

Comment: After "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception." it gets difficult to read. Could you please edit your question to make it a little easier to understand?